# Reg ex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string accepted from the user `movie="Jumanji"`

I want to search this string in a csv file using the variable name irrespective of the case. My file is like:

```
movieId     title        genres

1          Jumanji(1995)   Adventure|children|fantasy

2          Friends(1994)   Romance|Comedy
```

After searching it should return the genre.

Comment: What have you tried exactly?

Comment: it only matches when i enter movie="Jumanji(1995)" i.e when i enter the exact same data and not when i enter movie="jumanji" only. Also i need to match it irrespective of its case

Comment: Show the code you used to search the file. We can help to improve the code, but most users here are less eager to do all the work for you.

Comment: `if "jumanji".capitalize() in movie`?

Answer (score 1):

Load the file and search iteratively over each line:

```
with open('your_csv_file.csv', 'r') as infile:
    lines_with_movie_name = [line for line in infile if movie.lower() in line.lower()]
```